# Data cache invalidation in Linux?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How can I invalidate the cache on linux machine running on x86 ARCH (if possible). GCC has [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) `__builtin___clear_cache()` built-in function to invalidate the instruction cache, but I could not find any way to invalidate the data cache.

Comment: Can you specify the reason you want to do this? Since X86 has full cache coherency, you should not need to invalidate with any operation.

Comment: It may be (like [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol)) but what if you do not need this automatic behaviour and control the cache line yourself. There are various occasion when you have to invalidate the cache line because its stale or you want to start all over again, etc. Example: NIC (Network Interface Cards)

Comment: You can use the [clflush](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_30.html) instruction. But you need to provide a virtual address inside the cache line to be flushed.

Comment: `__builtin___clear_cache` does not flush instruction caches on x86; they're coherent with data caches and don't need flushing.  What it does do is make gcc realize that stores are not "dead" to a buffer that you cast to a function pointer.  See https://godbolt.org/g/pGXn3B, which repeats `dec eax` M times then appends a `ret`.  Without `__builtin___clear_cache` or a compiler memory barrier like `asm("":::"memory");`, the `memset` is optimized away.  (See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/the-repetitive-byte-counter/160236#160236 for why I wrote that code.)